# How to monitor the spark streaming jobs in Hadoop cluster?

Tags: spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

We are manually monitoring the streaming spark jobs , we need to automate the spark jobs monitoring , if the job failed or went second attempt need to restart the spark jobs and send mail to monitorning team